# Export function from bash and run it through command line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script in server.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function start {
    docker-compose up -d --build && docker exec php bash -c "composer install; vendor/bin/phinx migrate" && \
    docker exec web bash -c "cd web; npm install; pm2 start node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js --name web"
}

function stop {
    docker-compose down
}

export -f start stop
```

I want to call these function from command line such as

```
$./server.sh start
$./server.sh stop
```

Is this possible ? Right now it doesn't do any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `export -f start stop` like this.

Here is a good thread explaining how to use it:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash

If you wish to call your start/stop method from the command line, you will have to expose it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function start {
    docker-compose up -d --build && docker exec php bash -c "composer install; vendor/bin/phinx migrate" && \
    docker exec web bash -c "cd web; npm install; pm2 start node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js --name web"
}

function stop {
    docker-compose down
}

if [[ "$1" == "start" ]]; then
  start
fi    

# [... same idea for the stop one ...]
```

And then call it like `$ ./server.sh start`

This is an example as there is more efficient ways to manage arguments.

Hope this give you some insights.

Comment: Thanks great ! actually the goal is to package the software to someone so he can run directly.  It works

Answer (score 2):

Your script ignores its command line arguments, so passing it `start` or `stop` is pointless.

The only thing it does is to define (and export, for some reason) two functions, so running it in a separate shell does nothing.

What you can do is source the script in the current shell:

```
. ./server.sh
```

Then you will have two functions available that you can run:

```
start
```

and

```
stop
```

(both in the current shell).

If you want it to work differently, you'll have to redesign your shell script.